# Passing date from Angular to Python

Tags: python, angular

I have Flask back-end and Angular front-end. My backend working well when I test it via Postman. I send the this kind of data

```
{
    "date": "2018-01-27"
}

@app.route("/schedule", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def schedule():
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    get_date = request.get_json(force = True)
    day_name = datetime.datetime.strptime(get_date['date'], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%A')
    week_number = datetime.datetime.strptime(get_date['date'], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%V')
```

...

But I have problems when I'm trying to send it from Angular.
My service :

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestService {
  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getData(model): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/schedule",model)
      .map((response:Response)=>{return response.json() });
  }
}
```

My component:

```
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    openSelectorOnInputClick: true,
    satHighlight: true
  };

  data:any;

  public model:any = { jsdate: new Date()};

  constructor(private http:RequestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getData(){
    this.http.getData(this.model.formatted).subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result;
    });
    console.log(this.model.formatted)
  }
```

the error:

```
zone.js:2933 POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/schedule 400 (BAD REQUEST)
ERROR Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final/…object: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)</p>↵", status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "BAD REQUEST", headers: Headers, …}
```

And this is structure of this.model:

```
{date: {…}, jsdate: Sat Jan 27 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима)), formatted: "2018-01-27", epoc: 1517000400}
```

What should I send to get a normal reponse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
this.http.getData({date: this.model.formatted})
```

And modify your post methot like that

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/schedule", JSON.stringify(model), {headers: headers})
```